# printing out the Questions from a Data set-Regex Python

Tags: python, regex, data-analysis

```
'Respondent,Randomized respondent ID number (not in order of survey response time)',
 'MainBranch,"Which of the following options best describes you today? Here, by ""developer"" we mean ""someone who writes code."""',
 'Hobbyist,Do you code as a hobby?',
 'Age,"What is your age (in years)? If you prefer not to answer, you may leave this question blank."',
 'Age1stCode,"At what age did you write your first line of code or program? (e.g., webpage, Hello World, Scratch project)"',
```

Here , is the Data Set I have and I want to separate only the questions .
Here , is the code I tried .

```py
lst=[]
regex=re.compile(r'(.*?)\?')
for quest in data:
    if regex.match(quest):
        lst.append(regex.match(quest))
print(lst)
```

It does find the questions but gives me the whole sentences .

```
match=\'MainBranch,"Which of the following options best d>
```

Is there any way I could just get the questions without quotes  or name of the person.

and the output I get is in this format , match object

```
['<re.Match object; span=(0, 68), match=\'MainBranch,"Which of the following options best d>',
 "<re.Match object; span=(0, 32), match='Hobbyist,Do you code as a hobby?'>"
```

Can I just simply get them as strings not match objects and store into a list ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `re.search(r'"(.*?)\?').group(1)`

Comment: Have you tried the patten above?

Comment: I am getting an error : ```expected string or bytes-like object```

Comment: I can't see how you get it. Please add the code you are using into the question.

Comment: Alright I got it . But its giving me for a single string . Output is: ```'Which of the following options best describes you today'```   What am I missing so that I can do it for all the strings?

Comment: I think am missing out on the probability that the output string may even contain symbols as(-,',"(,),/,\) and therefore need to edit the regex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224316/discussion-between-kirti-purohit-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `r'"([^?]*)\?'` regex to match `"`, then capture any zero or more chars other than `?` into Group 1 and then match a `?` to ensure it is a question, and then use `regex.search(quest)` to find a match anywhere in the string (`re.match` only searches at the start):

```py
import re
data = ['Respondent,Randomized respondent ID number (not in order of survey response time)',
 'MainBranch,"Which of the following options best describes you today? Here, by ""developer"" we mean ""someone who writes code."""',
 'Hobbyist,Do you code as a hobby?',
 'Age,"What is your age (in years)? If you prefer not to answer, you may leave this question blank."',
 'Age1stCode,"At what age did you write your first line of code or program? (e.g., webpage, Hello World, Scratch project)"']
lst=[]
regex=re.compile(r'"([^?]*)\?')
for quest in data:
  m = regex.search(quest)
  if m:
    lst.append(m.group(1))
print(lst)
```

Output:

```py
['Which of the following options best describes you today', 'What is your age (in years)', 'At what age did you write your first line of code or program']
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/wg9nq1).